# Regex - find whole sentence with first letter uppercase

Tags: regex

I was trying to match (using regex) string which can contains anything but it must start with uppercase letter, for example:

```
"Harkon's Sword"
```

I wrote something like this:

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9,;'\"\\s]*\s
```

which finds `"Harkon's "`but not the other word. Can you help with this?

Other examples of strings I want to find:

```
"Dragonbane",
"Skaal Armor",
"Horn of Jurgen Windcaller"
```

Comment: Will there ever be anything else on the line that you don't want to match?

Comment: No, string can contains anything - what is important it must start with uppercase letter.

Comment: Not sure what language you're using. Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/kP6rO4/2) do what you're expecting?

Comment: Your original regex probably isn't matching because it's requiring your string ends with some space, in addition to escaping `\s` in the second character group. Remove this from the end `\s`, and change `\\s` to `\s` (depending on the language) and it'll probably work.

Comment: @excaza Yes, it does! Thank you very much for help! I'm now ashamed of myself, this is so easy...Thank you once again for replay and for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the entire line if it starts with a capital letter, you can simplify your regex and just match a capital letter at the beginning of the string:

```
^[A-Z].*
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP6rO4/2)